# What's the disadvantage of encrypt mariadb?

Tags: mariadb

I know if I [encrypt mariadb](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/data-at-rest-encryption/#encryption-key-management),  no one can steal my data.
What's the disadvantage of  encrypt  mariadb?

Comment: Correction:  "No one can steal your data _without getting the key from your application_."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a bit open-ended, but here are few things that might be considered disadvantages:

- Encryption and decryption are CPU-intensive tasks, so you will see increased CPU utilization. If your server is CPU-bound, this may be a problem.
- As a consequence of the above, encryption/decryption add certain latency to your I/O operations, so query performance might be negatively affected.
- There is certain effort involved in managing encryption keys. Also, if you ever lose them, you lose all your data as well.

Comment: any specific disadvantage in mariadb?

Comment: I rarely find a CPU-bound MySQL/MariaDB server that can't be improved by fixing indexes/queries/schema.